# Do Search engines trawl secured pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I am developing a web site using ASP.net MVC. There are pages that are locked down and are only accessible by logged in users. If the user isn't logged in when trying to access these locked pages, then they are redirected to the login screen.

My question is, can search engines crawl these pages even though they are locked down to authorized users? If they can, should I be adding the meta tag `rel="nofollow"` or is there a better solution in MVC to block whole folders and its contents from search engines?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: If they can't log in, how can they crawl it? Search engine crawlers aren't special in any way.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed as much, I just wanted to be 100% certain.

Comment: You can block search-engine access by using [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

Answer (score 2):

No the secured pages will also deny access to any search engine crawler.

Answer (score 2):

the google bot will not be able to load the HTML in side the secured pages, however if there are links from the site to the secured page and if its loading the HTML, that could be index by google.